# MySQL employee database

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlfiddle

I am having trouble designing a query that does the following:

**List employee names, employee numbers, and their respective total earningPerProject using the following database schema:**

```
department(primary key(deptName), deptName, deptCity) 
employee(primary key(empNum), empName, empCity)
project(primary key(projectNum), projectName, budget)
worksOn(foreign key(empNum), foreign key(projectNum), deptNum, jobTitle, startDate, earningPerProject)
```

I am able to display the employee names and employee numbers but when it comes to the total of the earningPerProject for each employee I am lost.

Some employees are listed more than once, and I realize I have to use the aggregate functions **SUM()** and **COUNT()**, but I haven't figured out a way to do this successfully.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(empName), employee.empNum, earningPerProject FROM employee, worksOn
WHERE worksOn.empNum = employee.empNum;
```

Could someone assist me with some hints or example queries.  I am not sure how I would go about doing this.

Comment: what do you mean by "Your (empName) is just the same as empName" ?

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function here, you aren't calling it and empName isn't an argument. The syntax happens to allow parentheses around SELECT clause column expressions. LIke (empNum + 7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you must use the `GROUP BY` clause and `SUM()` to compute to total earningsPerProject for the given employee.

`DISTINCT` is not necessary. In your code you used `DISTINCT(empName)` which looks like you want to eliminate duplicate employee names in the result. It is possible to have two employees with the same name so retrieving only unique names could leave some employees out of your results. This is why we use things like `empNum` as a primary key instead of names. You actually want to retrieve the distinct combos of `empNum` and `empName`.

You are correct that there can be duplicate `empNum` in the `worksOn` table because a given employee could work on multiple projects. The `GROUP BY` will group together all rows having the same `empNum` and `empName` and combine them into a single row thus eliminating the need for `DISTINCT`. (More below)

Here I have modified your query to include the `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT employee.empNum, employee.empName, SUM(worksOn.earningPerProject)
  FROM employee, worksOn
 WHERE employee.empNum = worksOn.empNum
 GROUP BY employee.empNum, employee.empName;
```

---

### JOIN

The syntax used in your `FROM` clause (`FROM employee, worksOn`) where you list the tables to be joined together on the same line and comma separated is what is known as an implicit join. This syntax was deprecated with the release of SQL-92 according to [Join (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).

Best practice dictates that you switch to using the new syntax known as the explicit join by using the `JOIN` keyword with the added `ON` keyword to describe the link between the tables.

The new `JOIN` syntax is functionally equivalent to the old implicit join syntax. Both produce the same results.

```
SELECT employee.empNum, employee.empName, SUM(worksOn.earningsPerProject)
  FROM employee
  JOIN worksOn ON employee.empNum = worksOn.empNum
 GROUP BY employee.empNum, employee.empName;
```

---

### DISTINCT

`DISTINCT` is a SQL keyword that eliminates duplicate result rows based on the expressions in your `SELECT` list. If you request only one expression (`SELECT empCity FROM employee`) it returns the unique values for that expression (it only shows each city once). If you have request more than one expression it returns unique combinations of those expressions.

Many database engines use `GROUP BY` to calculate `DISTINCT` results so using them together is usually redundant.

Your query includes some unfortunately legal SQL syntax. You put parentheses around `empName` which gave `SELECT DISTINCT (empName), employee.empNum, ...`. This syntax is misleading because `DISTINCT` is a keyword and not a function and the parentheses here are not used by `DISTINCT`. When `DISTINCT` is used it applies to all expressions in the `SELECT`. In this case removing the parentheses does not change the meaning though it does make it more clear.

These three queries are equivalent:

```
SELECT DISTINCT empName, employee.empNum, ...

SELECT DISTINCT (empName), employee.empNum, ...

SELECT DISTINCT empName, (employee.empNum), ...
```

Parentheses in SQL can be used to group expressions and are typically used to force the order of evaluation when dealing with operators such as <, >, =, *, /. Placing parentheses around a single expression does not change its value. While you thought you were using `DISTINCT` for just `empName` you really were just wrapping the expression `empName` in parentheses which effectively did nothing.

You can test this by running this query

```
SELECT empName FROM employee
```

and this query

```
SELECT (empName) FROM employee
```

and you will see the same results.

Comment: The query works.  If you have the time, could you shed some light in your own words on how `JOIN` works exactly? Thanks @Noah

Comment: Maybe you could explain that the `DISTINCT` applies to all selected columns and the `(empName)` [sic] is just parentheses around the expression `empName`.

Comment: What would be the difference between your query and the following query:
`SELECT employee.empNum, employee.empName, SUM(worksOn.earningPerProject) from employee, worksOn
  where employee.empNum = worksOn.empNum
 GROUP BY employee.empNum, employee.empName;`

Comment: @Noah got it.  Thanks. the `distinct` reserved word sure is misleading.  I'll also try to use `JOIN` from now on in my queries.
Thanks